# Postgres pg_dump to Azure Blob storage

Tags: postgresql, azure, pg-dump, azure-blob-storage

Is it possible to use Postgres' `pg_dump` to write the backup to an Azure Blob storage? I have almost 2TB of data on a VM in a postgres DB and I need to migrate all the data to a blob storage.

Comment: that would take ages, dump locally and move to storage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per my experience , it's impossible to write data directly from Postgres DB  to Azure Blob Storage currently.

You can refer to the following ways to implement your needs.

1. As @4c74356b41 said in comment, you could dump your backup data to locally and move them to storage. Considering you have 2TB of data or even more, it's going to be a long process.
2. You could create a data disk which is stored in Azure Blob Storage ,attach it to your vm , then you could write backup data to disk. More details , please view this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/about-disks-and-vhds).
3. Or you could use Azure Files with Linux or Windows , attach it to your vm via SMB. More details , please view this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-linux).

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks. A few options - I'll take a more in depth look.